# Merge multiple Point Clouds into a single 3D object

Tags: 3d

I am testing the Intel RealSense D435 camera and have been able to create multiple Point Clouds (.ply) of a certain object. Each Point Cloud is taken in a different viewing angle of the object.

Now I wish to merge all these point clouds into a single, 3D Object. I have tried CloudCompare but this requires manual cropping of outliers and noisy data, as well as translating each Point cloud.

I wonder if there is a piece of code that can merge point clouds together and remove noisy data in order to have a rough 3D Object?

Answer (score 1):

CloudCompare has statistical outlier removal (called SOR) function that can eliminate all lonely points for you. I would filter each *.ply first and then try to carry out a cloud to cloud registration. For registration, you can use MeshLab or use 30 days trails of commercially available software such as Faro Scene. Scene won't accept *.ply file though, so you need to convert your files to *.e57 first. Good luck.